# Why does #ifndef __func__ return true?

Tags: c++, func

The following code,

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef __func__
#   ifdef __FUNCTION__
#       define __func__ __FUNCTION__
#   else
//#       error This compiler supports neither __func__ nor __FUNCTION__
#   endif
#endif


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << __func__ << std::endl
              << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl
              << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

gives the following expected output,

```
main
main
int main(int, char**)
```

However, if I uncomment the `else` condition, compilation fails because neither `__func__` nor `__FUNCTION__` are defined. How can this be? They clearly are defined as seen in the output above. Is there some simple principle regarding `#ifdef`/`#ifndef` that I'm missing here?

Comment: I have no clue, maybe __func__ and friends are not macros, can you also tell what compiler and OS you are using.

Comment: I'm using a cross-compiler based on GCC/G++ 4.7.2. The code does NOT produce this error when using Visual Studio 2010. I've only seen this problem when I cross-compile.

Comment: Thanks, [this older page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.3/gcc/Function-Names.html) says that they are not preprocessor macros, but are compiler built-ins.

Comment: @Chris O, Thanks. However, it still leaves the question: why would a native compile succeed and a cross-compile fail? Shouldn't the behavior be the same regardless of definition?

Comment: They are macros in [Visual Studio 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(v=vs.100).aspx) and variables in [GCC/G++ 4.7.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Function-Names.html).

Comment: @DaBler, Thank you. That does explain the difference. Now I can work around that. Best!

Comment: You should check for existence of compiler identifying macros (`__GNUC__`, `_MSC_VER`), instead of `__func__` and `__FUNCTION__`.

Answer (score 4):

`__func__` is not a macro. It is a magic variable, as are `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Function-Names.html:

> GCC provides three magic variables that hold the name of the current function, as a string. The first of these is `__func__`, which is part of the C99 standard:
>
> The identifier `__func__` is implicitly declared by the translator as if, immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
> ```
>  static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> ...
>
> `__FUNCTION__` is another name for `__func__`.
>
> ...
>
> In C, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is yet another name for `__func__`. However, in C++, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` contains the type signature of the function as well as its bare name.